# How to attach image view as an email attachment?

Tags: android, imageview, email-attachments

I am generating pie chart on image view, I want to send it via email.

How to convert image view's image to email attachment, as its not available in resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `getDrawingCache()` on your image view. This returns the cache bitmap of the view. Read documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29).

Save the bitmap as PNG, create a mail and attach and send.

```
Bitmap bmp = imgView.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, fos);
fos.close();

/* Create a Action_SEND intent and attach the FILENAME image to the mail. */
...
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FILENAME); // FILENAME is URI
...
startActivity(....);
```

Comment: How to give URI for Imageview? I meant FILENAME.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most Android-friendly way would be to use the ACTION_SEND Intent. The code would look something like this:

```
    path = "/path/to/image/"
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: But my image is not stored on device, it is generated on runtime. How I attach that?

Comment: I don't know how your code works, but saving the image to Internal or External Storage and getting a URI isn't too painful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a lot of extra work is going on here.  If you have the ImageView available at run-time, we'll call it mImageView, then you could do something like this:

```
Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Now you have a Bitmap image that you can append to an email as an attachment.  I haven't prototyped it to make 100% sure this will do exactly what you're looking for, but it seems a lot more elegant than saving it to the SD card just so you can stream it back to a Bitmap and attach it to an email.

Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll try to prototype out something

Thanks,
David

Comment: The OP wants to send the image as a mail attachment.. So `PNG` format is the best choice.. Attaching a bitmap is out of the question...

Comment: OP wanted to know how to get access to the Drawable, there was no mention of compression and no reason that a bitmap is out of the question. It's a larger format, that could be compressed as an optimization. The question revolves around how to get access to the image itself

Comment: Compressing the bitmap before sending does not hurt in anyway. So why not do it. Why would anyone want to send a larger image when he can do a lossless compression on it and reduce its size. Also the email intent accepts a Uri and not a bitmap reference..so we cannot send the image without saving it first.

Comment: I agree that compression is a good idea but you don't know the OPs use case, so we shouldn't be designing their code. The question was how to get access to the Drawable, which I provided. They are free to do any additional processing they desire, but the question had nothing to do with what format the image should be compressed to.